# What is this problem in j2me with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, eclipseme

I have this problem using j2me with eclipse and eclipseme: when I start running the application, it doesn't do anything and I get this result...

```
Warning: Running JAM, Ignoring all other options (but "-Xheapsize", and OTA flags if provided)
Running with storage root C:\Users\adham\j2mewtk\2.5.2\appdb\MediaControlSkin
Running with locale: Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256
Running in the identified_third_party security domain
The MIDlet suite was not found.
Execution completed.
3390735 bytecodes executed
24 thread switches
1665 classes in the system (including system classes)
17352 dynamic objects allocated (519548 bytes)
1 garbage collections (0 bytes collected)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part seems to be:

```
The MIDlet suite was not found
```

Check the path to the jad file. Then check the path to the jar file within the jad (Normally it's just the name of the jar file, and you have them in the same folder). Next, check the Manifest file in the jar file. Check that it identifies the Midlet class in your jar. Next check that the Midlet class is actually a subclass of MIDlet.

Comment: Ah, then you're running it all from eclipse then... I'm not sure, but I'd imagine that you can specify your MIDlet properties in the project properties. IIRC, eclipse has some sort of jad editor